# Is there a way to randomly generate TTS voices using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, voice, pyttsx

Is there a way to randomly generate voices using Python?

I have no idea where to start, but my best guess would be doing something along these lines:

```
class CustomVoice(voice)
    def __init__(self, pitch):
        self.pitch = pitch
```

I cannot seem to find a base object to clone it off though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is not clear... But I can help you with this...

To generate a voice in python, there are many ways like Online and Offline.
But for the sake of simplicity, I am going to demonstrate the offline way to get your issue done fast.

Step 1 : Install the ***pyttsx3*** library

`pip install pyttsx3`

Step 2 : Import the Library in the python code

`import pyttsx3`

Step 3 : Prepare the text

`toSay = "Hello I am the Voice from python "`

Step 4 : Say !

`engine.say(toSay)`

Step 5 : Actually Say !

`engine.runAndWait()`

That's done !

Comment: Sorry about the clarity issue. I'm asking how do I generate a type of voice. Like the voice that it's saying it with. For example, the voice metadata has an age factor, which I assume changes the pitch of the sentence? (this is mainly what i'm looking for, since you can already change speed)